# Wallet Portuguese seed words?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, language

How are the words for the seed chosen?

For e.g.

togoles doesn't exist its togolês and even that its a very odd word

again oigale its oigalê and still nobody uses this

Probably its supposed to avoid easier bruteforcing of a seed?

I'm asking because Portuguese words for the seed are very unusual and some are even wrong...

I would be glad to contribute for a seed Portuguese dictionary if there's a way to do so.

Thanks !

Comment: Why the concern? The odder the words in the seed, the more secure it is.

Comment: @StrawbsUK it makes it harder to remember, which kinda defeats the purpose of a mnemonic seed

Answer (score 1):

You can see the list of Portugese words Monero uses [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/portuguese.h).

Only the first 4 letters of each word matters (for Portugese). For other languages, it may be 3 or 4. You can test this by restoring from your mnemonic seed, changing '**togo**les' to '**togo**abc'. It should still restore.

If there is a better word you feel should be used instead of togoles that begins with togo-, then feel free to suggest changes on the Monero Github.

Comment: I think the whole dictionary should be wrote again for must common words for example: "carro sapatilha chaves aula tecto" = "car sneaker keys class ceiling" , for easier mnemonic words!

Comment: Nevermind, dictionary is huge probably I just ended with the hardest words...

Comment: @guestpt The words are not random. Unfortunately, we cannot simply make a list of a few hundred Portuguese words unless they meet certain criteria.